# Write/read to object

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to make a simple way to write/read to object element in WP7. Something is not working properly. My way of thinking and what I have already done is like that:

First I create a class that represents my object. I added static string just to see if everything works well:

```
namespace SimpleObject.Objects
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public string entrytitle { get; set; }
        public string entrycomment { get; set; }
        public string entrycat = "works";

        public Entry() { }
        public Entry(string Entrytitle, string Entrycomment, string Entrycat)
        {

            this.entrytitle = Entrytitle;
            this.entrycomment = Entrycomment;
            this.entrycat = Entrycat;
        }

        public string entry { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then, as I read in some articles I need to make some changes in App.xaml.cs Here we go then:

> using SimpleObject.Objects;

Before App() I put this:

> public static Entry E;

Then in App() this:

```
UnhandledException += new EventHandler<ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs>(Application_UnhandledException);

E = new Entry();

InitializeComponent();
```

Then my UI is two pages. One is a form to input data, second to read. Under application bar button I have:

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Entry E = new Entry
            {
                entrytitle = TitleTextBox.Text,
                entry = CommentTextBox.Text,
            };

            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            MessageBox.Show("Category added!");

        }
```

Finally page that present results:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock1.Text = App.E.entrycat;
            TextBlock2.Text = App.E.entrytitle;
        }
```

And second TextBlock gives me nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never setting the global static values.  In your button click, it should be this:

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    App.E.entrytitle = TitleTextBox.Text,
    App.E.entrycat = CommentTextBox.Text,

    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: After this change, none of them give any result.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you use the Debugger. Do the Values i App.E get set in Page 1? Are they still there when you clink the Button in Page 2?  Unless something else is overwriting the values (or E itself), or the app logic isn't exactly what you have posted, then it should be working.

Comment: Generally I would like to learn how to manage data in WP. Any good tutorial you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

another option is to forgo the global variable which you're basically only using to pass the value from one page to the next.

You can do this with query string values just like in a web application and pick them up on your page load handler.

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml?title=TitleTextBox.Text&comment=CommentTextBox.Text", UriKind.Relative));
}
```